# Separate Access Fields which contain multiple values to unique lines with properly corresponding data

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a field in Access where there are multiple comma separated values (Field one has values of `"1, 2, 3, 4"` in the row `1, "2, 2, 3"` in row two).

The first field has `1-7` (but can be as big as `1,101`) values in it.

The second field will have the same number of values corresponding to Field1's row,

However the commas may be oddly placed (I assume this can be solved with a trim or a left offset function when analyzing this field ", `1, 2, 3`).

What I need is for the thousands of these lines to no longer have duplicate entries and for them to each be their own line. A solution that can scale is important and the use of the entire Microsoft Office suite is allowed to be used.

From a line of:

```
 Field1           Field2

 1, 2, 3, 4      , 1, 1, 4, 4
 2, 2, 3         , 2, 3, 3
```

The output would look like:

```
 Field1  Field2
 1       1       
 2       1
 3       4
 4       4
 2       2
 2       3
 3       3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```
Sub GetNumbers()
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select Field1, Field2 From Table1")
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        'Get the fields values and 'trim away' any blanks.
        Dim field1 As String
        field1 = Trim(rs("Field1").Value)
        Dim field2 As String
        field2 = Trim(rs("Field2").Value)

        'If the strings now begin with a ',', remove it.
        If Left(field1, 1) = "," Then field1 = Mid(field1, 2)
        If Left(field2, 1) = "," Then field2 = Mid(field2, 2)

        'Split the strings to an array by ','
        Dim arrField1() As String
        arrField1 = Split(field1, ",")
        Dim arrField2() As String
        arrField2 = Split(field2, ",")

        'Loop the arrays (important is that the number of elements is equal in both arrays. This depends on your data!)
        Dim index As Long
        For index = LBound(arrField1) To UBound(arrField1)
            'Output the values and again 'trim away' any blanks
            Debug.Print Trim(arrField1(index)), Trim(arrField2(index))
            'Here you also can store the values to another table if you want/need.
            'If the new field is a text field:
            'DoCmd.RunSQL "Insert Into Table2 (Field1, Field2) Values ('" & Trim(arrField1(index)) & "', '" & Trim(arrField2(index)) & "')"
            'If the new field is a number field:
            'DoCmd.RunSQL "Insert Into Table2 (Field1, Field2) Values (" & Trim(arrField1(index)) & ", " & Trim(arrField2(index)) & ")"
        Next index
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad overview of how to go about it. You will have to do the detailed work yourself, since this site is about getting you unstuck from a problem not writing code for you.

- Loop through your records. For each:

  - Use `Replace` to replace ", " with ","
  - Use something like `IIF(Left([Field2],1=",",Right([Field2],Len([Field2])-1),[Filed2])` to clean up leading commas. Similarly for trailing commas if necessary
  - Use `Split` to break down both fields into arrays of strings.
  - Use `UBound` to determine how many numbers in each record (it should be the same on both fields so it doesn't matter which one you test).
  - Use a `For` loop to go through the arrays

    - Use something like `DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO MyCleanedUpTable (Field1, Field2) VALUES (" & Field1Array(i) & "," & Field2Array(i) &  ")"` to add each pair to your new cleanup up table.